# Изменение текста элемента CListView

Tags: mfc, c++

Подскажите, как можно реализовать следующее: имеется CListView с элементами, правый клик по элементу вызывает контекстное меню, содержащее пункт "переименовать". Хотелось бы реализовать возможность ввода нового имени элемента непосредственно в CListView (аналогично переименовыванию файлов в Windows). Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лично я у кого-то подсмотрел и делал так же через Ж.
Когда требуется редактировать, над соотвествующем поле ListView отображаешь Edit с длдиной и шириной как у редактируемого поля. После выхода из Edit производишь вставку текста в ListView

Может там есть чего поумнее, но я в свое время не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, речь можно вести как о CListView, так и о CListCtrl

Во-вторых, достаточно переопределить ф-цию, вызываемую при отрисовке контрола и нарисовать там все, что нам заблагорассудится. Вроде как это будет OnDraw.

В третьих, попробуйте [LVS_EDITLABELS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xxsdd7z(v=vs.80).aspx)